# IPython nbconvert Syntax error?

Tags: python, pdf, syntax, ipython

I am attempting to simply export an IPython notebook to a PDF. I cannot get past a syntax error that makes no sense to me.

```
ipython nbconvert "TestBook.ipynb" --to=latex --post=PDF
File "<ipython-input-45-98f03ab096ad>", line 1
ipython nbconvert "TestBook.ipynb" --to=latex --post=PDF
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm new to python and IPython, but I'm at a complete loss here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to run this in the python shell

```
>>> ipython nbconvert "TestBook.ipynb" --to=latex --post=PDF
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ipython nbconvert "TestBook.ipynb" --to=latex --post=PDF
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Exit from the shell, and run it from the command line instead.

Comment: This worked. Is there not a function within IPython to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As [@karthikr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1628832/karthikr) said, you are trying to run the code in the python shell.
If you want to run the command from a python shell you could use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

To run your command in windows powershell:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'ipython nbconvert TestBook.ipynb --to=latex --post=PDF'
subprocess.run(['powershell', '-Command', cmd])
```

To run your command on the bash:

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'ipython nbconvert TestBook.ipynb --to=latex --post=PDF'
subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd])
```

If you are on Jupiter notebook you could easily use this line:

```
!ipython nbconvert TestBook.ipynb --to=latex --post=PDF
```